# why does my cpu get too hot while playing game?

Tags: cpu, temperature, gaming

recently, some of my system drivers have been updated. before that the CPU temp fluctuated between 60 and 70 centigrade (in games),but after updating,the temp has risen to 80 centigrade while playing game. I also disabled startup apps to prevent CPU high usage but it still gets too hot.

Comment: Your temps are fine. It will throttle at 99 degrees, and will shut off to protect damage if too hot.

Comment: yes,I concur with you but in the long term, it definitely causes permanent damage hardware.

Comment: If you are using a stock CPU cooler, those temps are normal.

Comment: As long as ~80 is as hot as it gets and it doesn't go over ~90, there is no chance of it ever causing any damage. Even going over ~90 *shouldn't* cause any issues. As @NiallUK mentioned, the chip will shut itself off to prevent damage when it gets too hot, but even that shutoff temperature is well above what you're talking about here.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to keep the temperature as low as possible because this will affect your overall performances.
In case of CPU running games is one of the heaviest things , that's why your temperature rise.
Every update on OS or even video card driver can require more CPU usage than before especially in windows.
To fix the problem you can upgrade your cpu to a better one checking the motherboard compatible list or you can buy a all in one liquid cpu coller that is not so difficult to install.

here an example.

[image]